# C# Caching is dropping rows when synchronizing to the database

Tags: c#, caching

im using temporary table to hold data to display it in gridview and then from that table to database, im using cache for this process.

**Problem :**
    sometimes one record from the table is not loading into the database. if im using break point its working.

```
if (Cache["Info"] != null)
{
       Table = (DataTable)Cache["Info"];
       Table.Rows.Add(0, this.ddl1.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                this.ddl1.SelectedValue.ToString());
       Table.Rows.Add(Table.Rows.Count, this.ddl2.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                this.ddl2.SelectedValue.ToString());
}

foreach (DataRow dr in Table.Rows) 
{
  this.SetInfo(Convert.ToInt32(dr["No"]), Convert.ToString(dr["ID"])); 
}
```

query to insert data:

```
INSERT INTO sample(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6)
VALUES
(@field1, @field2, @field3, @field4, @field5, @field6)

try
{
    if (this.sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        this.sqlCon.Open();

    this.sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("procedure_name", this.sqlCon);
    this.sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    this.sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@field1", SqlDbType.VarChar));
    this.sqlCmd.Parameters["@field1"].Value = value;

    this.sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@field2", SqlDbType.VarChar));
    this.sqlCmd.Parameters["@field2"].Value = value;

    this.sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@field3", SqlDbType.VarChar));
    this.sqlCmd.Parameters["@field3"].Value = value;

    this.sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@field4", SqlDbType.Int));
    this.sqlCmd.Parameters["@field4"].Value = value;

    this.sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@field5", SqlDbType.VarChar));
    this.sqlCmd.Parameters["@field5"].Value = value;

    this.sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@field6",SqlDbType.DateTime));
    this.sqlCmd.Parameters["@field6"].Value = value;

    this.sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Comment: datatable(temporary table) having 3 records but only 2 records are getting  uplode to the database.last record is missing in the database. if im using break point its working properly..:(

Comment: You are just swallowing exceptions and carrying on, maybe the DB is throwing a useful error.

At least in your catch put throw ex; and when it's running and the app crashes it will crash and report an exception string so at least you can read it.

Answer (score 0):

If thats the case maybe your temporary table is getting dropped....maybe due to a connection close call...also could you elaborate on what you are trying to do....

take a look at this link to know more about temporary tables

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html

Comment: im using C# datatable as temporary table

Comment: if your table has all the rows then check the code where you pass the data to the database...try putting it in a try catch block...

Comment: is this query you are asking?

Comment: the way you have written the code it seems that you are not calling a stored procedure but running a simple query so please remove the this.CommandType line or set it to text. procedure_name can be declared as a string variable to hold the query. also Robert has commented correct that you are just swallowing the exception so please write throw ex in the catch block to be alerted if any error occurs

Answer (score 0):

try using this code instead, might help:

```
var Table = Cache["Info"] as DataTable;

if (Table != null)
{       
   ......
```

Though it is only syntactically different, but as your code is working if you put break point this may do the trick. It is just like restarting dev server or rebooting the machine :)

If its still not working please read this great post by [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/11379.aspx)

EXAMPLE: I've setup two pages, on first one i'm adding values to datatable in cache (function AddClicked) and on second page I'm retrieving datatable and binding to a gridview and this is working fine.

```
private DataTable CreateTable()
{
    var dtb = new DataTable();
    dtb.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SerialNo", typeof(int)));
    dtb.Columns.Add("Item");

    for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        dtb.Rows.Add(new object[] { i, i + "" });

     Cache.Add("data", dtb, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, 
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);

    return dtb;
}

protected void AddClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtItem.Text)) return;

    var table = Cache["data"] as DataTable;

    if (table == null) return;

    var i = table.Rows.Count + 1;

    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { i, txtItem.Text });

    BindData(table);
}
```

THIS IS ON SECOND PAGE

```
    private void BindData()
    {
        var dtb = Cache["data"] as DataTable;
        if (dtb == null) return;
        grdTest.DataSource = dtb;
        grdTest.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: foreach (DataRow dr in Table.Rows)
                        {
                           
                            this.SetInfo(Convert.ToInt32(dr["No"]), Convert.ToString(dr["ID"]));
                        }

Comment: sorry these process is working fine in side too...
problem is when we are trying to upload it to the database

Comment: will you please post code you are using to upload to db? In the code given in question you are adding only two rows.

Comment: is this query you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Caching is only temporary and may be dropped at any time.

You should use the session or application objects instead.